# react js getting hold of data even after page reload

Tags: reactjs, laravel, frontend, passport-jwt

Hello guys i have this component where after login it will **history.push** to dashboard together with the props attached to it, now my problem is when i refresh the dashboard page all those props are gone how can i maintain those props event if i refresh the page  data will still be there?is it possible?

**here is my LOGIC:**

```
Parent(ClassAppComponent)->Child(ClassLoginComponent)->GrandChild(LoginForm)
```

the props contains token and i use the token as JWT auth to query the server and send back the data which is acording to the token
 **example:**

```
axios.post("/server/address",{
   Authorization: 'Bearer'+ ' ' +this.props.token
    withCredentials:true
})
```

with above code **i can query the server using the props no issue**,but when i refresh the page it wont work anymore since it is using the props.token as parameter, i tried another method which store thr token to the session, problem is i need to create two separate query a query after push and another query after page reload. is there another way i can make this simple with one query only.. please advice me if i am approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: yeah i understand then i have to create another query using the storage data ..is there any other way?

Comment: what do you mean another query, can you please explain? you need to send an Authorization header every time you make a api call.

Comment: when you use history push and attach props from parent to child obviously u will get the props correct? example is token u can use it as parameter to header query, now when page reload u wont be able to enhirit anymore the props u will then need to access the storage get the token and use it as parameter inside the header

Comment: with that type of approach i need to set another if or else statement and complicate the push method

Comment: i am looking for one time aproach both can re use

Comment: okay. Before you do history push, store token in local storage, and on dashboard page access the token from local storage. Do need to rely on props on dashboard page for token, because you already have the token in local storage. I hope it helps.

Comment: when using localstoragesetitem + push it will not gonna work, the storage will become null, instead i use state create success:false replace the push with setstate(success:true) then render method use if statement ..now it works i conclude that push can only be use in certain things ..